# Find matlab command window handle/reference

Tags: matlab, command-line

From matlab it is possible to get a (java) reference to the matlab editor using these commands:

```
desktop = com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance;
jEditor = desktop.getGroupContainer('Editor').getTopLevelAncestor;
```

Thanks to [Undocumented Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/)

Does anyone know how to get a reference to the Command Window?

It is impossible to obtain it the same way as the group titles do not include 'Command Window'

```
cl = desktop.getGroupTitles()

cl =


java.lang.String[]:
    'Editor'
    'Figures'
    'Web Browser'
    'Variables'
    'Comparison Tool'
    'Help'
    'Time Series Plots'
    'Scopes'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps like this?:

```
desktop = com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance;
cmdwin = desktop.getClient('Command Window');
```

Maybe you need to add this too:

```
cmdwinview = cmdwin.getComponent(0).getViewport.getComponent(0);
h_cmdwin = handle(cmdwinview, 'CallbackProperties');
```

All of this comes from this forum thread: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/257842.

Remark: I am not a MATLAB/Java guru. Google, on the other hand, I can use :)

Comment: I have tried google, but I couldn't find it. In general I only answer to matlab questions but this time I needed help myself :)

Comment: Original reference in: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/cprintf-display-formatted-color-text-in-command-window/